# How can I remove in software top bar?

Tags: top-bar

How can I remove in software top bar? Here I am not talking about activities top bar.

Here a pic of what I am talking about

[image: Visual Studio Code Screenshot]

Comment: Do you want this behavior exclusively for VSCode or all program ?

Comment: what if I only want to do it in vscode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Unite Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) (-> [github](https://github.com/hardpixel/unite-shell)).

[image: Unite Gnome Extension; Picture taken from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/ - CC-BY]

Comment: Thanks for your help :)